# test iptables rules using netcat is not working

Tags: iptables, netcat

I have 4 virtual machines using virtual box. One virtual machine work as a router that connects 3 networks. Im trying to drop all communications entering the router machine, excpet for some services. The interfaces ips that I have in each machine are:

Virtual machine 1 that work as router:

```
eth1: 193.136.200.254 
eth2: 10.10.0.254 
eth3: 10.254.0.254
```

Virtual machine 2:

```
eth1: 10.10.0.2 
eth2: 10.10.0.3
```

Virtual machine 3:

```
eth1: 193.136.200.2
```

Virtual machine 4:

```
eth1: 10.254.0.1
```

I define the rules below on the router machine:

```
IPTABLES -P INPUT DROP
iptables -A INPUT -s 193.136.200.3 -d 193.136.200.254 -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

And now Im trying to test if this is working using netcat. So in the router machine Im running the command:

```
nc -u -s 193.136.200.254 -p 53 193.136.200.3 53
```

And in thevirtual machine 3 Im running:

```
nc -u 193.136.200.3 53
```

Then I write a random word in one machine but it is not appearing in the other machine. So it isnt working. Do you know what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are connectiong itself, when you type the command:

```
nc -u 193.136.200.3 53
```

If you want to connect to your router from machine 3 try this command:

1. `nc -u -s 193.136.200.3 -p 53 193.136.200.254 53` instead of `nc -u 193.136.200.3 53`

Comment: Thanks. With your solution when i run the command it appears: nc: bind failed: cannot assign request address.

Comment: If I change 193.136.200.3 to 193.136.200.2 I dont get this error but when I write someting I get nc: write error: connection refused.